# Java whitespaces in the @RequestBody string replaced by '+'

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, whitespace

I am trying to send a string like 'Ekin Frontend' in the request body and it is converted to 'Ekin+Frontend=' at the backend.
I think Springboot converts these whitespaces. Does anyone have any idea ?

Here is my code block;

```
@PostMapping("/error")
public boolean addError( @RequestBody String errorMsg) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is what is happening.  Open up your dev tools on the browser and look at what the browser is sending to the server (ie Network Tab).  I suspect the browser thinks it's a form submission and is encoding the payload with a form encoding.  You should also look at the mime-type being sent in the `Content-Type` header in dev tools.  If it's `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then that's a pretty good indicator you're sending to the server that way.

If you are literally trying to send a String you'd want the `Content-Type` header to be "text/plain" or "text/plain;charset=utf-8" since we aren't in ASCII anymore.  If you are trying to send plain text you'll have to do that with Javascript to make it work because you'll have to set that mime-type manually.  The browser won't do that on its own.

But, if you are trying to submit an HTML form then you should just let the browser do its thing, and change the server to use @ModelAttribute and remove @ResponseBody annotation.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial